# Joining two SQL queries to filter duplicate records joining another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a bit new to write complex SQL queries. There are two tables and we call them `employee` and `status`.

I need to filter duplicate records based on the key and status.

Key : `|emplyee_dep_id|employee_reg_date|employee_rep_manager|`

It is a composite key.

And there is a column in the `Employee` table called `emp_status_id`. In the `Status` table, there are two columns `status_code` and `status_id`.

Finally, I need to filter duplicate records based on the composite key with status "promoted" joining two tables.

I have written two queries but need to develop a single query. Could you help me to combine these two queries, please?

Sample data

```
|emplyee_dep_id|employee_reg_date|employee_rep_manager|status_id|email|
| 1            | 20-01-01        |  Anne              |  3            |a@a.com|
| 1            | 20-01-01        |  Anne              |  3            |u@a.com|
| 1            | 20-01-01        |  Anne              |  3            |y@a.com|
| 1            | 20-01-01        |  Anne              |  3            |h@a.com|
| 1            | 20-01-01        |  Anne              |  1            |b@a.com|

|Status_id|status_code|
| 3       | Promoted  |  
| 1       | Probation |
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    emp.emplyee_dep_id, emp.employee_reg_date,
    emp.employee_rep_manager, employee_status
FROM  
    employee emp
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         emplyee_dep_id, employee_reg_date, employee_rep_manager, 
         COUNT(*) AS CountOf
     FROM 
         employee
     GROUP BY 
         emplyee_dep_id, employee_reg_date, employee_rep_manager
     HAVING 
         COUNT(*) > 1) emp1 ON emp.emplyee_dep_id = emp1.emplyee_dep_id 
                            AND emp.employee_reg_date = emp1.employee_reg_date
                            AND emp.employee_rep_manager = emp1.employee_rep_manager


SELECT 
    employee_status
FROM
    Employee
INNER JOIN 
    Status ON Employee.status_id = Status.status_id
WHERE
    Status.status_code = 'promoted'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it much clearer what YOU mean by "duplicate".

Comment: Do a second `INNER JOIN` to `Status` table and then `GROUP BY` the necessary fields.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `Employee` in the 2nd query, put the 1st query and join with status

```
SELECT e.*, s.status_code
from 
(
    SELECT  emp.emplyee_dep_id,emp.employee_reg_date,emp.employee_rep_manager,employee_status as status_id
    FROM employee emp
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    emplyee_dep_id,employee_reg_date,employee_rep_manager, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                    FROM employee
                    GROUP BY emplyee_dep_id,employee_reg_date,employee_rep_manager
                    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                ) emp1
                ON emp.emplyee_dep_id=emp1.emplyee_dep_id 
                AND emp.employee_reg_date=emp1.employee_reg_date
                AND emp.employee_rep_manager = emp1.employee_rep_manager
) E
INNER JOIN Staus s
ON E.status_id = s.status_id
where s.status_code = 'promoted'
Group by emplyee_dep_id,employee_reg_date,employee_rep_manager;
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/898b9f/2)